# Is there a way to save a flextable in R to a LaTex file?

Tags: r, latex, flextable

I would like to save a [flextable](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/index.html) to a LaTeX (.tex) file in R. Is there a way to do that? For example, how could I save this table?

```
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
ft
```